# How to Split and Format a String Representing Poker Hand History in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string representing a poker hand history that I need to split and format. The string contains information about two "runs" of a hand, and I need to separate these runs and format the information about each player's actions.

Clarification: mr.Anderson showed the same hand, but on the Board 1 he lost; on the Board 2 he won. That matches the input: `Seat 4: mr.Anderson (button) showed [As 6d] and lost, and won ($398.37)` - it means he lost on the board 1 and won on the board 2.

Example input:

```py
site_initial_handhistory = '''
Board 1 [6s 2s Td 5h 3c]
Board 2 [6s 2s Td 4h 7s]
Seat 1: MrBaguette showed [5c 6c] and won ($398.38), and lost
Seat 4: mr.Anderson (button) showed [As 6d] and lost, and won ($398.37)'''
```

Desired output:

```
*** SUMMARY ***
Board 1 [6s 2s Td 5h 3c]
Seat 1: Player1 showed [5c 6c] and won $398.38
Seat 4: mr.Anderson (button) showed [As 6d] and lost
Board 2 [6s 2s Td 4h 7s]
Seat 1: MrBaguette showed [5c 6c] and lost
Seat 4: mr.Anderson (button) showed [As 6d] and won $398.37
```

Comment: From where is the `Player1` string? or `with a` ?

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted ' with a' since it was unnecessary

Comment: So in two different boards mr. Anderson has shown the same hand? The input and output do not seem to correspond very clearly

Comment: Please show the code you are currently using to get the example 1.

Comment: @LucasMouraGomes mr.Anderson showed the same hand, but on the Board 1 he lost; on the Board 2 he won. That matches the input showed [As 6d] and lost, and won ($398.37) -- it means he lost on the board 1 and won on the board 2.

Comment: @Jesse Sealand Example 1 is a parsed data, I don't have a code that produced this.

Comment: So search for the comma between the result of board 1 and board 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like this:

```
import re

regex = r"(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.* and )(.*), and (.*)\s+(.* and )(.*), and (.*)"
replace = r"*** SUMMARY ***\n\1\n\3\4\n\6\7\n\2\n\3\5\n\6\8"
result = re.sub(regex, replace, site_initial_handhistory.strip())
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know the number of boards, you can do it this way:

```
site_initial_handhistory = '''
Board 1 [6s 2s Td 5h 3c]
Board 2 [6s 2s Td 4h 7s]
Seat 1: MrBaguette showed [5c 6c] and won ($398.38), and lost
Seat 4: mr.Anderson (button) showed [As 6d] and lost, and won ($398.37)'''

lines = site_initial_handhistory.splitlines()

boards = []
seats = []
for line in lines:
    if line[:5] == 'Board':
        boards.append(line)
    if line[:4] == 'Seat':
        if ',' in line:
            sections = line.split(',')
            info = sections[0].split(' and')[0]
            sections[0] = sections[0][len(info):]
            for section in sections:
                seats.append(info + section)
        else:
            seats.append(line)
            
n_boards = len(boards)

for i in range(n_boards):
    print(boards[i])
    for j in seats[i:len(seats):n_boards]:
        print(j)
```

Output:

```
Board 1 [6s 2s Td 5h 3c]
Seat 1: MrBaguette showed [5c 6c] and won ($398.38)
Seat 4: mr.Anderson (button) showed [As 6d] and lost
Board 2 [6s 2s Td 4h 7s]
Seat 1: MrBaguette showed [5c 6c] and lost
Seat 4: mr.Anderson (button) showed [As 6d] and won ($398.37)
```